# Dialog application with LISTBOX

Tags: c++, symbian

I'm creating an S60 application that will have a main dialog with a listbox of 5 or so items.

but i keep receiving a message : "application app1 closed" when trying to run the application on the emulator.

This is my resource file (app1.rss)content :

```
RESOURCE DIALOG r_dialog
    {
    flags=EAknDialogSelectionList;
    buttons=R_AVKON_SOFTKEYS_OPTIONS_EXIT; 
    items=
        {

        DLG_LINE
            {
            id=EPowerSMSDlg1Label;
            type=EAknCtSingleGraphicListBox;
            control= LISTBOX 
                { 
                flags = EAknListBoxSelectionList;
                array_id=array0;
                };
            },

              DLG_LINE

                 {

                 itemflags = EEikDlgItemNonFocusing;

                 id = EFindControl;

                 type = EAknCtSelectionListFixedFind;

                 }


        };
    }


RESOURCE ARRAY array0
{
    items=
        {

            LBUF { txt="Events Log"; }

        };
}
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing a panic. You should [enable extended panic code](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Extended_panic_code) to see which panic you are getting, and then refer to the [system panic reference documentation](http://developer.symbian.org/main/documentation/reference/s%5E3/doc_source/reference/SystemPanics/index.html) to see what it means.

In this particular case, at least your listbox item format is not correct. `EAknCtSingleGraphicListBox` enum value corresponds to `CAknSingleGraphicStyleListBox` class and [its documentation](http://developer.nokia.com/document/Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-759FBC7F-5384-4487-8457-A8D4B76F6AA6/html/classCAknSingleGraphicStyleListBox.html) states that

> list item string format: "0\tTextLabel\t1\t2" where 0,1,2 are index to the icon array

Your item text is missing those tab separators.